# React-slick or Nuka carousel with rows

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I just started learning ReactJS and had to port an existing template to a ReactJS one. Currently I'm having trouble implementing rows in react-slick. I've seen many asking for this since 2015, but it was not answered. Even the new Nuka Carousel created specifically for ReactJS from the same author as Slick-Carousel, did not implement support for rows.

What is the best workaround for having rows in react-slick or nuka-carousel?

Comment: I am also looking for the same didn't find any solution if any one have please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a little while since this question was posted, but React-Slick now supports multiple rows as a configurable setting with the keys **slidesPerRow** and **rows** as seen [here](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/multiple-rows).

```
export default class MultipleRows extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      rows: 2,
      slidesPerRow: 2
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you assist me with this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757342)?