# Finite variable width slider (that scrolls only visible slides), slides should always fill the display area

Tags: reactjs, carousel, create-react-app, react-slick

> I hope this is not a "big ask" but I'm stuck. I asked this issue on [github issues#1334](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1334) but I have not got any responsive from the maintainers of the project. Hopefully I can get help here.

### Overview

My issue is that I'm trying to adjust the [variable width](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/variable-width/) slider (from `react-slick` documentation) in order to be:

1. `finite`
2. `responsive` (to different viewports) (if possible to display as many slides according to viewport width)
3. `scroll only 100% visible slides`
4. slides should fill the `div` display area

#### Observations

1. So far, I have managed to make it:

   - `finite`
2. Regarding `responsive`, breakpoints don't work well for `variable width` slides.
3. `scroll only 100% visible slides`, This is very important when it comes to variable viewport width and when using variable width slides.
4. `slides should fill the`**div**`display area`, *finite variable width slides* when they reach the last slide, even though it was already visible by the previous scroll, the user can still scroll and what is visible is a huge area of blank slides, for example:
   [image: blank slides visible after last slide]

### The Code

The issue can be replicated and tested in [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/983v21ooq4)

...
...

Any help is welcome.